# Mapping positions to names based on date in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mapping, pandas-merge

I have a DataFrame of "positions" and the "date they came to office":

```
position  cameToOfficeDate
CEO       2020-06-01
CEO       2021-01-01
CEO       2021-02-02
Slave     2020-01-01
```

I want to map the `position` to employee's names for different `cameToOfficeDate` but based on the `commencementDate` of the `position`s too. For example, the CEO was Bill before 2021 and was Mark after 2021.

```
position  commenceDate  Name
CEO       2020-01-01    Bill
CEO       2021-01-01    Mark
Slave     2020-01-01    Elon
```

So the output should be:

```
position  cameToOfficeDate  Name
CEO       2020-06-01        Bill
CEO       2021-01-01        Mark
CEO       2021-02-02        Mark
Slave     2020-01-01        Elon
```

I am wondering how to create the mapping table structure. I tried using a dictionary but it doesn't allow comparing whether the `cameToOfficeDate` date is smaller than or bigger than the `commencementDate` of the `position`. Tried joining the table together on position too and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/dev/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html). Since `merge_asof` expects the keys to be sorted, we convert the dates to datetime objects and sort; then `merge`.

```
df1['cameToOfficeDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['cameToOfficeDate'])
df2['commenceDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['commenceDate'])
out = (pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='cameToOfficeDate'), 
                     df2.sort_values(by='commenceDate'), 
              left_on='cameToOfficeDate', right_on='commenceDate', 
                     by='position')
       .drop(columns='commenceDate')
       .sort_values(by=['position','cameToOfficeDate']))
```

Output:

```
  position cameToOfficeDate  Name
1      CEO       2020-06-01  Bill
2      CEO       2021-01-01  Mark
3      CEO       2021-02-02  Mark
0    Slave       2020-01-01  Elon
```